# XSLT sort by tag name and attribute value

Tags: xslt, sorting

I'm a noob with XSLT, so please excuse my ignorance...
I'm trying to sort a simple XML file by attribute value and tag name, but I struggle in accessing the value of the attribute.
Here is a complete example:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="e"></b>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
    <c></c>
</a>
```

And the expected result is:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <b attribute="e"></b>
    <c></c>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
</a>
```

Here is my attempt to solve this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
                <xsl:sort select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this obviously don't work at all...

In the above example I want to sort the *b* tag by their attribute value but as you can see the *d* tag is not sorted by attribute value because it's another tag name...

I wonder if this is possible using XSLT...
Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE----------------------**

I tried andyb solution that seems to work fine and looks pretty simple, but I have another issue with this solution.

Let's say I have this XML:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="e" optionalAttr="fg"></b>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
    <c></c>
</a>
```

I added an optional parameter for the *b* tag.
Applying andyb solution the optional parameter will be ignored, because it is not matched in the template. Here is the result:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <b attribute="e"></b>
    <c></c>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
</a>
```

Instead of the following which is what I expect:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <b attribute="e" optionalAttr="fg"></b>
    <c></c>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
</a>
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more powerful solution that does sorting based on element names and multiple attributes names and values. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multiple [`xsl:sort`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting) instructions, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
      <xsl:sort select="name()" />
      <xsl:sort select="@*" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and since the default *data-type* is "text" and the default *order* is "ascending" this gives the desired output.

**Edit**

This is strange, because for the following XML:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="e" optionalAttr="fg"></b>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
    <c></c>
</a>
```

and the XSL above, I get this result:

```
<a>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <b attribute="e" optionalAttr="fg"></b>
    <c></c>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
</a>
```

This includes the desired optional attribute but the order is different to the XML in the edited question (`<c></c>` is in a different position).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check this solution soon and keep you informed!

Comment: Just one question: using this solution I have a problem when I have two tags with the same name but one of these has an optional attribute that the other doesn't have then this attribute is lost because not copied (as it is not matched), any idea?

Comment: Happy to help :-) Can you add any example XML for this new problem? Editing the question is best as code cannot be formatted as nicely in a comment.

Comment: I am getting a different result. I am just using Firefox to test this at the moment. How are you testing the XSL? Also which output is correct, as I am seeing the elements in sorted order and the XML in your edited question lists them in a different position?

Answer (score 7):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation performs sorting by element name and multiple attributes nameand value**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
                <xsl:sort select="my:attributeScore(.)" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="my:attributeScore" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="pThis" as="node()"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vScore">
          <xsl:for-each select="$pThis/@*">
           <xsl:sort select="name()"/>

           <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'+',.)"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:sequence select="string-join($vScore, '')"/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided one, but added multiple attributes):

```
<a>
    <b attribute="e" x="y"></b>
    <b attribute="e" x="x"></b>
    <b attribute="b"></b>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
    <c></c>
</a>
```

**the correctly sorted result is produced**:

```
<a>
   <b attribute="b"/>
   <b attribute="e" x="x"/>
   <b attribute="e" x="y"/>
   <c/>
   <d attribute="a"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Wow this looks pretty good!! I can't test this solution right now, but I will soon be able to test it and I will keep you informed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've got an issue with this stylesheet. Seems like the function cannot be found: ID système inconnu; Ligne #24; Colonne #47; java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.attributeScore([ExpressionContext,] ).
ID système inconnu; Ligne #22; Colonne #44; java.lang.NullPointerException
[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.

Comment: @reef: It is in bold at the very start of the answer: this is *XSLT 2.0* solution. One cannot easily do something similar with XSLT 1.0. Also, as you are just starting with XSLT, the best recommendation you can receive is to use from the very start only XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Oh yes... didn't see it sorry. I am gonna try to use a Java API that can handle XSLT 2.0, I'll keep you informed.

Comment: @reef: Just good to know: You can use the Saxon 9.x XSLT 2.0 processor (there is a free, open-source version available).

Comment: I got the error "An attribute node (formula) cannot be created after a child of the containing element" using Saxon-HE 9.7.0.8N

Comment: @Matthew, The code in this answer has always worked -- for everybody. I don't have your code, so I can't say what is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this question and as I'm new at xpath and XSL thought i'll give it a shot.

I seem to have come up with a completely different solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*">
            <xsl:sort select="not(@*)" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:sort select="@*"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*/@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()[not(string-length(normalize-space()))]"/>
<xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It does depend on how you want the attributes to be order...

**Sample 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<a>
    <b attribute="e" ></b>
    <b attribute="b" ></b>
    <c></c>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
</a>
```

**Result 1**

```
<a>
  <d attribute="a" />
  <b attribute="b" />
  <b attribute="e" />
  <c />
</a>
```

**Sample 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<a>
    <b attribute="e" ></b>
    <b attribute="b" optionalAttr="fg"></b>
    <c></c>
    <d attribute="a"></d>
</a>
```

**Result 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>
  <d attribute="a" />
  <b attribute="b" optionalAttr="fg" />
  <b attribute="e" />
  <c />
</a>
```

Just wondering if anyone could see anything wrong with this approach?

Thank you in advanced