# XSLT, how to sort by element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a newbie in XSLT. I just come up with a question and hope someone can help.

Assume I have a source xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<docroot>
    <vc6>foo</vc6>
    <vc7>bar7</vc7>
    <vc8 arch="x64">amd64demo</vc8>
    <vc7>foo7</vc7>
    <vc6>bar</vc6>
</docroot>
```

I'd like to turn it into:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<docroot>
    <vc6>bar</vc6>
    <vc6>foo</vc6>
    <vc7>bar7</vc7>
    <vc7>foo7</vc7>
    <vc8 arch="x64">amd64demo</vc8>
</docroot>
```

that is,

1. child elements of  should be sorted by element name, so `<vc6`> comes before `<vc7`> .
2. If two children have the same element name, they should be sorted by their text value, so 'bar' is ahead of 'foo'.

How to write the xsl? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some examples of how to use `xsl:sort` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5962936/113848).  Something like this should work for you:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
      <xsl:sort select="name()" />
      <xsl:sort select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, you give the right answer. But, Could you update your answer so that attributes can be copied? Currently, with attribute in source xml, xsltproc 2.7.8 says "Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element".

Comment: No, it's still wrong. If there's a child element called AA and an attribute called ZZ, it will try to put the child element before the attribute.

Comment: Sorry, legoscia, I notice that you just swapped the ``@*`` and ``node()``, but still the error: "Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element". Have you verify it with some xslt software?

Comment: Right, now it's actually tested :)  Works for me with xsltproc.

Comment: as reported, I also get "Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element" with xsltproc, however @MichaelKay answer works just fine for me

Answer (score 5):

Revision of legoscia's answer:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
      <xsl:sort select="name()" />
      <xsl:sort select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Oops, your two <xsl:apply-template> elements are not in pairs. Even if I duplicate the </xsl:apply-template> end tag, side by side, to make it well-formed. xsltproc 2.7.8 outputs only ``<docroot/>`` , not the expected result.

Comment: Note that if you want to run that thorough e.g xsltproc you'll need to wrap it in<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">...</xsl:stylesheet>