# XSLT Best Way to Sort Duplicate Elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I'm new to XSLT and am trying to sort an arbitrarily sized XML document according to certain instructions:

1. All attributes should be sorted in alphabetical order
2. Child elements should be sorted in alphabetical order by element name
3. If two children have the same element name, they should be sorted using a consistent, well-defined process (preferably alphabetically in some way)

I'm currently stuck on implementing step 3. I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091085/xslt-to-sort-nodes-by-name) post for steps 1 and 2, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998029/xslt-how-to-sort-by-element-name) post in an attempt to implement step 3. My current implementation is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I noticed this isn't a perfect solution due to some edge cases, as when I run it on the following input:

```
<colours b="x" c="y" a="t">
    <blue/>
    <aa>
      <bb>y</bb>
      <bb>a</bb>
    </aa>
    <aa>
      <bb>a</bb>
      <bb>z</bb>
    </aa>
    <violet/>
</colours>
```

It outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<colours a="t" b="x" c="y">
   <aa>
      <bb>a</bb>
      <bb>z</bb>
   </aa>
   <aa>
      <bb>a</bb>
      <bb>y</bb>
   </aa>
   <blue/>
   <violet/>
</colours>
```

This output has the aa sections in the wrong order according to how the sort works (a,z should come after a,y) and I understand that it's because of the order the sort occurred in, but it seems the only workaround is to repeatedly execute this xslt on the output until no more changes are made.

From my understanding the secondary sort key from my implementation (<xsl:sort select="."/>) which I'm using to implement step 3 triggers when a duplicate element is encountered that can't be sorted alphabetically and uses the string value of the duplicate elements as the sort key. From what I've read, this string value is the the concatenation of the string-values of all its Text Node descendants in document order. I believe if the element is empty then its string value is the zero length string. However, I think this comes with another edge case where sorting can't occur for the following input:

```
<colours b="x" c="y" a="t">
    <aa>
      <cc/>
    </aa>
    <aa>
      <bb/>
    </aa>
    <violet/>
</colours>
```

No matter what order the aa sections are put in, the output is identical to the input, meaning no sorting is occurring in this situation.

Are there any improved solutions for handling sorting these duplicate element names? Or is my implementation the best approach xslt can implement and I have to stick with the workaround for the first case and accept the second as unable to be fixed?
An idea could be if there are two duplicate elements it sorts them by checking their next child node (in alphabetical order) recursively or something along those lines (add a third sort key?), though I'm unsure how to implement that in xslt.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: As advised by the commentors, below I've added to the third instruction to establish a more concrete specification.

> 3. If two children have the same element name, they should be sorted using a consistent, well-defined process (preferably alphabetically in some way)

If two children have the same element name, is it possible to define their sort key as a concatenation of their subtree of element names in document order? E.g., for the following code:

```
<colours>
    <aa>
      <cc>
        <rr/>
      </cc>
      <ff/>
    </aa>
    <aa>
      <cc>
        <ee/>
      </cc>
      <zz/>
    </aa>
    <violet/>
</colours>
```

The first aa sort key would be ccrrff while the next one would be cceezz. This way they can be sorted in alphabetical order (i.e., the second aa section would go first).

This should fix the issue in my second example (I'm fine with the workaround for the first), and I'm thinking that this sort key would be the secondary sort key going in between the two sort keys I have in my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, attributes in the XDM data model are unordered. That means there's no guarantee that they will be serialized in any particular order. You may be lucky, it depends on the implementation.

As for element sorting, I would start by ensuring whitespace text nodes are eliminated: use `xsl:strip-space elements="*"`. But I think your real problem is specifying your requirements rather than writing code to implement them. You've given us a couple of examples to play with, but two examples doesn't constitute a specification. You could achieve your two examples by computing a sort key that's something like `string-join(*/(local-name()||string()))`, but that might not give the results you want for your next example.

Comment: My apologies, I realized I should've tried to be more concrete with my 3rd step specification. I've updated the post with more information. 
Although your sort key works for the example I provided, would you be able to take a look at my updated post for a solution idea as you're correct that there are other examples that still don't output the desired results. 

I'm trying to get this xslt to be able to sort any abstract xml doc and so I've got to keep the sort's general enough to work on any size and structure of xml.

Comment: @JustinWeller, I think you underestimate the task to "sort any abstract xml doc" and to have that "work on any size and structure".  What would you want to do with mixed contents documents?

Comment: I think you're still trying to do "specification by example", and there are lots of details missing, such as namepace handling.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay says, there is no exact specification, I have no idea what you would want to do with mixed contents or any comments or processing instruction nodes, but perhaps, you have basically all text data in attributes and leaf elements, the following might help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="sort(@*, (), function($a) { namespace-uri($a), local-name($a) }),
                sort(*, (), function($el) { namespace-uri($el), local-name($el), $el/descendant::*!(namespace-uri(), local-name(), .[not(*)]!data()) })" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="sort(@*, (), function($a) { namespace-uri($a), local-name($a) }),
                sort(node(), (), function($n) { data($n) })" />
      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It exploits the power of the `sort` function allowing you to generate as much sort keys as you need/want dynamically, so you are not bound to a certain number of `xsl:sort`s.