# Sort parent element among its siblings based on the text of its children

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

I think my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835952/revisited-sort-elements-of-arbitrary-xml-document-recursively) might be a bit overwhelming for people, so I'm trying to solve it in chunks.

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="sort">
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
    <xsl:sort select="./*"/>
    <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="./*[text()]"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The first `sort` statement `<xsl:sort select="name()"/>` works and I understand it.

The second `sort` statement `<xsl:sort select="./*"/>` seems to do almost exactly what I want, but it does not take the `text()` of a child node into account.  I don't really understand why this `sort` statement is doing what it is doing.  Adding it was just one of many attempts to solve my problem.

The third `sort` statement `<xsl:sort data-type="text" select="./*[text()]"/>` is my attempt to pick up where the second `sort` statement left off.  It does not work and it generates the error when using [Saxon-HE 9.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.4):

> Caught: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: A sequence of more than one
>   item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:sort

What I'm attempting to do here is sort a parent element correctly among its siblings based on the text of its child element(s).

Help would be much appreciated as the weight of XSLT is crushing me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*">
  <xsl:sort select="."/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The above code will take all children element nodes of the current node, sort them by their text value, and push them at your template rules in text sorted order.

From what I read in your snippet, do you really want to sort the children by their element name?

You should almost never have to address `text()` nodes ... the value of an element is the concatenation of all its descendent `text()` nodes.

Comment: Are you saying to get rid of all the `sort` statements I have and replace them with that one in your answer?  That does not seem to sort anything unfortunately.

Comment: Then you have to post a sample of data, because your requirement is not well described.  You are asking us to critique your code without knowing the precise problem being solved.  I am confused when you say "sort a parent", because all of your posited sort statements are dealing with children.  What is the parent of the parent?  In my answer, the nodes being sorted are being sorted by their text value which is the concatenated text value of their children.  Which is what I thought you were asking.

Comment: See the example code in the question I linked to in this question.